# Azure functions: executable file not found

Tags: azure, azure-functions, terraform, azure-function-app

I create an Azure linux function using the UI and when I try to deploy to it I get the following error.

OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:349: starting container process caused "exec: "func": executable file not found in $PATH": unknown

My entry is 'func start'. From what I understand this means that the container doesn't seem to have the executable for func. Any ideas why this would happen? It seems to work sometimes and other times doesn't work at all

Comment: Actually retested this again and have seen this problem without Terraform too. The deployment was successful a few times and then started failing when I reran the devops pipeline without any changes to configuration or the app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question here: This happened because I sent the wrong runtimeStack which was auto inserted by the devops ui when I choose JS, It was then trying to run the app in docker

DOCKER|microsoft/azure-functions-node8:2.0